# Python Tkinter get tkMessageBox response

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have the following code, button:

```
response = ttk.Button(frame,text='Install java', command=wizard.aksyesno)
response.pack(side='bottom')
```

and method:

```
def aksyesno(self):
    return tkMessageBox.askyesno('Install Java?', 'Do you want me to install java?')
```

How can I get the value of the user response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
if tkMessageBox.askyesno('Install Java?', 'Do you want me to install java?'):
    #function/method to install java here
```

EDIT: Whoops. Forgot how it worked. Edited my code to be correct. You can include an `else:` to do something else in the user selects "no".

Answer (score 0):

You can use what Al.Sal said, or alternatively, if you really need to store the result you can use a `BooleanVar`:

```
result = tkinter.BooleanVar()

def aksyesno(self):
    result.set(tkMessageBox.askyesno('Install Java?', 'Do you want me to install java?'))
```

and then use `result.get()` when ever you wanna access it.

Comment: When I do this the mesagebox is lunched just when the application starts, I need it lunch when the button is clicked and retrieve the value after that.

Comment: It works fine for me on 2.7. I think the problem @zulq might be that you're calling `aksyesno` somewhere. Can you post some more code?

Comment: Yes am calling it somewhere else, will however accept your answer. I've changed the implementation to use checkbutton instead.